# bash show-all-if-ambiguous turns on spontaneously

Tags: bash, tmux, readline

I am using tmux and bash. I find that, at seemingly random intervals, my running shells have `show-all-if-ambiguous` set to on. This is a significant annoyance to me, since many of my operations are in directories with very large numbers of files, where the show-all behavior disrupts the screen state. I have `set show-all-if-ambigous off` in my `.inputrc`, and have never enabled anything like this in any config file. The problem occurs in apparently any long-running shell. Running `bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous off'` successfully disables it again, but this is temporary.

Why does this behavior occur, and how can I make it stop?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in `bash`. If you figure out steps to reproduce the problem it should be reported to developers because it probably is memory corruption bug. Which version you have (`bash --version`)? I'm running version `4.3.48(1)-release` and I've never seen anything like you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after struggling with it for a while, I eventually just set `PROMPT_COMMAND="bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous off'"`. Which is a hack and doesn't address the real issue, but does what I need, viz. "make it stop doing that".

Comment: that is a clever workaround but I would guess if you need hacks such as this, your shell is already corrupting its memory and may fail in some other unexpected way in the future unless the root cause is fixed. (I'm assuming that your diagnosis is correct and you do not have any code that turns that feature on and as a result, the only thing that can enable that feature is a memory corruption bug that accidentally writes to the memory location containing the current flag value in `bash` process.)